# TSQL query with group by error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that I am running to return some stats for my tool. Currently it is working returning all information but I have recently added a new column to be able to get the totals by location and this is where I am stuck.

Below is my query:

```
 SELECT   B.[segmentName],
                 count(A.[segmentID]) AS total,
                 A.[meetingID],
                 C.[center]
        FROM     Focus_Meetings_Segments AS A
                 INNER JOIN
                 Focus_Segments AS B
                 ON A.[segmentID] = B.[id]
                 JOIN Focus_Meetings as C
                 ON C.[id] = A.[meetingID]
        WHERE C.[center] = @location
        GROUP BY A.[segmentID], B.[segmentName]
        ORDER BY total DESC
        FOR      XML PATH ('segment'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```

The new column added was `center` to the Focus_Meetings table.

The error I am getting is that meetingID is not contained in the aggregate or group by clause.

Is there another way to write this query so I can get it to run?

Comment: Your query makes no sense - you're grouping by `A.segmentID` and (supposedly) also counting it, instead of reporting it in the `SELECT` list.  This query wouldn't have worked even before you added `C.center` to the query.  I think we need sample starting data and desired results.

Comment: The real question is did you even consider pasting the error message into google first -.-

Comment: Yep, found many posts on Stack that didnt help; hence the question and reason for this site..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `GROUP BY A.[segmentID], B.[segmentName]`

to `GROUP BY B.[segmentName], A.[meetingID], C.[center]`

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `GROUP BY` in a query, all fields in the select list should be aggregated, or listed in the group by list.

You have to aggregate `A.[meetingID], C.[center]` (using aggregation function such as SUM, COUNT, MIN, AVG, etc), or you have to list them in the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

When using aggregate functions (like `SUM` or `AVG`), all columns that are not used by aggregation functions *must* be on the `GROUP BY` list of columns.